# How to read hex and mhx extension in CAPL Script

Tags: capl

I HAVE 
ReadBinFile ()   //Reads 2048 byte from bin file
{

transferlength = fileGetBinaryBlock(buffer, 2048 , fileHandle);
}

Now i want to read .hex and .mhx extension files i could not find the inbuilt function what is the option to do this in capl script.

Answer (score 0):

*.hex or *.mhx format files can be read with help of OpenFileRead function.
the below piece of code will help to read the .hex file.

```
void readhexfile(void)
{
    dword i;
    char  LineBuffer[0xFF];
    int   ByteCount;
    char  CountAscii[5];
    int   Data;
    char  Ascii[5];
    dword readaccess = 0;
    dword bufferpointer = 0;
    byte buffer[1*1024*1024];  //1MB hex file size
    if ((-1) != strstr_regex(FILENAME, ".hex"))  //FILENAME-> Sysvariable
    {
        readaccess = OpenFileRead (FILENAME,0);
        /* --> identified as IntelHEX-Input */
        if (readaccess != 0)
        {
            /* read line until cr+lf */
            while (fileGetString(LineBuffer, elcount(LineBuffer), readaccess) != 0)
            {
                // check for Record Type 00 (Data Record)
                if (LineBuffer[0] == ':'
                        && LineBuffer[7] == '0'
                        && LineBuffer[8] == '0'
                        )
                {
                    // extract ByteCount parameter
                    strncpy(CountAscii, "0x", elcount(CountAscii));
                    substr_cpy_off(CountAscii, 2, LineBuffer, 1, 2, elcount(CountAscii));
                    ByteCount = atol(CountAscii);
                    // extract Data parameter
                    for (i = 0; i < ByteCount; i++)
                    {
                        strncpy(Ascii, "0x", elcount(Ascii));
                        substr_cpy_off(Ascii, 2, LineBuffer, 9+i*2, 2, elcount(Ascii));
                        Data = atol(Ascii);
                        buffer[bufferpointer++] = Data;
                    };
                }
            }
            fileClose(readaccess);
        }
    }
}
```

the Similar approach can be used for reading .mhx file format.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert a `*.hex`/`*.mhx` file into a binary using [`srecord`](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/man/man1/srec_examples.html#BINARY%20FILES):

```
srec_cat file.hex −o file.bin −binary
```

Then you can read the resulting binary file with `fileGetBinaryBlock()`.

If you need to process `*.hex` files dynamically, you can call `srec_cat` directly from your CAPL code using `sysExec()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 dword openFileRead(char filename[], dword mode);
```

This function opens the file named filename for the read access.

If mode=0 the file is opened in ASCII mode; 
if mode=1 the file is opened in binary mode.

```
To open hexfile
dword HexFileHandle;

HexFileHandle = openFileRead(HEX_File_Path, 0);
```

The return value is the file handle that must be used for read operations.

If an error occurs, the return value is 0.